Mold in bedroom closet behind vapor barrier. Best way to proceed?
We've been dealing with an issue in our home for the past few years with this closet. Originally, there was a lot of cold coming from this portion of the closest (which also lead to some surface mold on the original drywall) which we sorted at one point by adding more insulation in the attic and then also more insulation within the walls themselves.
https://imgur.com/a/K3d7DyK
Now, we're seeing this mold buildup near the top. Not sure if there's any mold in the nearby walls at this point but this is a wall we left untaped so it was easy to get in and inspect after we had torn it up to add more insulation to the walls. For background, we live in Canada so our winters get quite cold but this recent mold seems like it may have showed up in recent months since it seemed to be fine for a bit but more recently the odor from the closet got worse.
Thoughts on best way to proceed from here or further diagnostics to perform?

Quite possible the problem is above and/or behind the closet(attic or outside wall).  Mold likes to have moisture.  Leaving the door open or changing to a vented door might be enough, if insulation/vapour barrier is good.

Are you sure it is mold and not some type of sealer?

If you are referring to the black strip(s) across the top and at the inside corner of one picture, this is acoustic sealant which is used to install the vapor barrier. It is non-hardening and may migrate with heat. I see no evidence of mold in your photographs.

Ya, my first thought was that there was some mold along with the sealant but on closer inspection, I think you're right. I'm waiting on a moisture detector to see if there isn't anything going on in other parts of the closet because I'm not seeing the mold right now either but there definitely has been a strong odor of late.

If the insulation in the wall was open to the attic, you might have some visitors as they like to bury themselves in the fiber. Acoustic sealant does not have much of a smell.
